# How to copy all elements of an array with generics except default values in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, generics

```
    Item item = arr[i];
    arr[i] = null;
    N--;
    if(N > 0 && N == arr.length/4){
        Item[] temp = (Item[]) new Object[N];
        int j = 0;
        for(int id = 0;id<arr.length;id++){
            if(arr[id] != null) temp[j++] = arr[id];
        }
        arr = temp;
    }
    return item;
```

I want to copy all elements of an array that is generic except the default values in the array. Also I need to remove some elements in the array by setting the value at that position to null. If the array is an integer array, the default value of all elements are 0. However, it is possible that there are some 0 that is not default value.
This code is wrong, because it will copy the default values in the array.

Comment: This can't really be done in Java.  There is (currently) no "default" value.  And ints don't work with generics.  You have to use Integer instead, and it has a default value of `null` not zero.  Summary: can't get there from here.

Comment: @markspace - Not quite.  It would be possible to write a method where you passed the array as an `Object`, and under the hood it handled each of the 8 different primitive array types with its own separate code path (or using reflection).  But that would be a bad idea.  (And even the notion of not copying the zeros in an `int[]` is a bit weird.  Sure, zero is the default ... but a zero could also be a "non default" value.)

Comment: @StephenC Well, that would not use generics though, and I think the OP was asking how to do with with generics.

Comment: This is extremely unclear.  There is no such concept as a "default" primitive `int` that distinguishable from all other possible `int` values.  If you were using `Integer` then the default could be `null`. Also the code sample has serious issues: what is `N`? If `arr.length` is not a multiple of 4 the loop will never end.  I think this is an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info).  Tell us what your ultimate objective is to get some appropriate assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Pulling together the comments into a coherent answer.  (Kudos to @markspace and @Jim Garrison.)

First of all, you cannot solve this problem *with generics* for the simple reason that a generic parameter has to be a reference type; i.e. a class, or an array type.  Therefore, you cannot express the `int` in `int[]` as a generic type parameter.  Or to put it more broadly, generics will not help you to deal with primitive arrays.

There is a (bad) solution that works for primitive types.  Basically, you have to pass the array with the type `Object`, then do a bunch of `instanceof` tests and deal with primitive and object arrays as (erm) 9 separate cases.  (Or use reflection, and take an order of magnitude or more performance penalty)

So what about using `Integer[]` instead of `int[]` and so on?  Well, you could do that ... and it would allow you to come up with a generics-based solution.  But then you have the issue that the default value for array elements is `null` not zero.

---

The other thing to note is that the semantics you seem to be asking for is a bit weird in the case of primitive types.  Consider `int[]` for example.  Yes, zero is the default value for uninitialized array values, but you can't distinguish a zero element that is a default value from a zero element that arose because the application *assigned* zero to that slot.  (And to take it to its logical conclusion ... consider the `boolean[]` case.)

So perhaps, if you want to be able to distinguish default values from non-default values, you *should* be using `Integer[]` rather than `int[]` ... and making use of the fact that `null` and `Integer.valueof(0)` are different.

---

But either way, the problem you have posed is difficult ... and given the nature of the difficulties, it is probably the wrong problem.  You need to look for an alternative approach that avoids the need to solve this problem.